# UI design similar to iOS in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-titlebar

Questions : I want to implement similar look and feel of the title bar default in ipad. How can provide similar look and feel??

Comment: Don't do this, instead use Android's UI patterns.

Comment: Why use ios Patterns while Android provides its own best patterns?

Comment: Well to help the author, sometimes customers just FORCE things on you :) BUT if you have full control of the app. Then just NO!

Comment: Please take a look at the following site: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html, it is unusual and often undesired to use an alternative UI design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

You can hide the title bar from an activity by setting the theme to `Theme.NoTitleBar`, and you would have to add a layout to the top of the each activity to make it look like a title bar. This is what I have done in the past.

Alternatively, depending on what version of Android you're supporting then you should use [Action Bars](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

As Warpzit has said, you should try to make things look as native as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try harder and make apps feel native. But if you for some reason only have this choice then just create a topbar.xml view and then use the xml `<include/>` tag in all those views where you need the topbar. You then need to make some methodes for handling back clicks and headline changes.

But again this looks horrible on android, this looks horrible, this feels wrong, this can be done better and this is really not adviced.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create Android application that has its pattern look and feel, so user doesn't need to learn new UX in your app.